# Is a successor for TeX/LaTeX in sight?

Tags: documentation, latex, tex

TeX/LaTeX is great, I use it in many ways. Some of its advantages are:

- it uses text files, this way the input-files can be diffed and many tools exist to work with text
- it is very flexible
- it has a stable layout: if I change something at the start of the document, it doesn't affect other things at the end of the document
- it has many extensions to reach different goals (a successor would start without extensions, but would have a good extension-system)
- you can use standard build control tools to support complicated documents (thanks dmckee)
- you can encapsulate solutions and copy&paste them to new documents or send them to others to learn from (thanks dmckee)

But on the other hand some little things are not so good:

- it is hard to learn at the beginning
- it is complicated to control position of images
- a few things are a little counter-intuitive
- sometimes you have to type too much (begin{itemize} ... \end{itemize})

So, does there exist a successor/alternative to LaTeX or at least is some hot candidate for an alternative in development. A real successor/good alternative would keep the advantages and fix the disadvantages, or at least some of them.

Comment: Add to your list of advantages: "You can use standard build control tools to support complicated documents---and indeed to supply two formats (say the one the graduate school insists on, and the one that looks good and kills fewer trees) of a single document."

Comment: Another: "You have the power to encapsulate things that you learn for others who might find them useful."

Comment: @dmckee: How do you use standard build tools (make et al.) when you don't know in advance how many times (pdf)latex needs to be run to produce its final output?

Comment: @j_r_h: Take a look at latexmk and rubber: http://www.pps.jussieu.fr/~beffara/soft/rubber/

Comment: @j_random_hacker: `make refs bib pdf` or something similar where the first two force a spare pass... Not elegant, but it works.

Comment: Another advantage (of TeX using textfiles): You can use standard versioning tools such as CVS, SVN..., which in turn allows for (some degree of) collaborative working on a document; you can externalize parts of a document into separate files, which again supports collaborative work.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13370/5763

Comment: QuarkXPress & Adobe InDesign are far superior than TeX/LaTex. Time to move on.

Comment: @j_random_hacker You have pointed out another flaw! TeX requires multiple passes (sometimes).

Comment: @dns I know nothing about QuarkXPress, but Adobe InDesign doesn't have a human-readable text-file format, right? How do you collaborate while working with InDesign, or even version control your documents (I'm not just talking about going back to a previous version, but branching and merging documents)?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://typst.app/

Answer (score 128, accepted):

There is a [LaTeX3](http://www.latex-project.org/latex3.html) project that has been going on for basically forever. In that sense, it is a successor to the current LaTeX2e.

You forget/ignore the primary goal for TeX when it was created -- "TeX is a new typesetting system intended for the creation of beautiful books". The goal of TeX was typesetting, and its primary concerns were things like "Breaking Paragraphs Into Lines" (*Donald E. Knuth and Michael F. Plass, Software--Practice and Experience, Vol. 11, pp. 1119-1184, 1981*), ligatures, kerning, beautiful fonts (Knuth worked with *Hermann Zapf* in creating typefaces like AMS Euler), and precise control over layout of text on a page.

LaTeX was a later set of macros built on top of TeX that introduced "document management" capabilities like automatic numbering of equations and sections, cross-referencing, and so on. It goes by "LaTeX: a document preparation system".

One can very well imagine successors to LaTeX, alternatives that offer LaTeX's document management capabilities, and perhaps do it better -- like DocBook. (Well it's based on XML, but...) But it is hard to imagine alternatives that will replace TeX, the typesetting engine itself. TeX is probably among the programs with the least number of bugs in it -- Knuth offers $327.68 for every bug found in TeX, and has done so for a long time. A lot of thought has gone into it, with Knuth's characteristic pursuit of perfection. Every aspect of it is configurable, the code is public domain (well except for the restriction that if you make modifications you must call it by some other name -- this is because of TeX's goal that the same TeX file typeset on any machine anywhere in the world should produce an exactly identical-looking document forever into the future), and books have been written about TeX: The Program itself, and also about all the bugs that were discovered in TeX.

Some of TeX's ideas have been incorporated into Adobe's Indesign (for example), and those typesetting engines too have some innovative ideas, but TeX still remains superior. [Note: Knuth didn't intend TeX to be the standard forever, only "for the next 100 years or so" until something better comes along. For all we know, one might.]

There are TeX-based alternatives to LaTeX, such as ConTeXt and LuaTeX. It is possible that there are tasks for which they are better suited.

To answer your other objections: Although LaTeX has possibly introduced more complexity than is necessary, the TeX part of the learning is unavoidable -- if you want to create beautiful books there are some things you *have* to know, no matter what. And it is not hard to control position of images; TeX was designed to give you control over every [point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)) on the page, but to exercise that control you may have to go beyond the simple constructs (although I've never had to...) And if you use a good editor or macros, you won't have to type too much \begin{itemize} ... \end{itemize}; that's just a lame complaint :P

Comment: Great answer. One quibble, though: LuaTeX is replacement for *TeX*, which ConTeXt is an alternative to LaTeX (and may well replace it).

Comment: I thought he offered $2.56 (or one hexadecimal dollar) for bugs, not $327.68 .  Am I right or wrong?

Comment: @Joey, it's $2.56 for errors in his technical books, $3.16 for errors in the 3:16 book, and the amount for bugs in TeX and METAFONT started at $2.56 and doubled each year until reaching $327.68.

Comment: The biggest pain about Latex is that there is no standard compiler that works in one go, and produces meaningful errors. There is also no clear single-way of doing things, nor any good user friendly place to find "packages" and know what they do. All the websites for the latex related topics look and navigate like in 1995.

Comment: LuaTeX is not an alternative to LaTeX, it is an extended TeX engine (like pdftex, XeTeX) on which both LaTeX (then called LuaLaTeX) and ConTeXt can run. (I think it is the default for today's ConTeXt.)

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: Yes, I know, my mistake. But Will Robertson already mentioned that in the first comment, so I didn't bother editing the answer.

Comment: I know comments are not the best place for asking questions, but has anyone actually compared TeX's, pdftex's and luatex's codebase to assess the percentage of TeX's code in both later "extensions"?

Comment: I bet DocBook (with WYSIWYG) will replace LaTeX in the future.

Comment: @AndriyDrozdyuk I wish I could upvote your comment 1000 times.

Comment: @helcim I'm answering 9 years late, but pdfTeX and XeTeX are roughly ~55% and (relying heavily on system libraries) 35% bigger than Knuth TeX respectively. (From my answer [elsewhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505627/how-many-lines-of-code-does-the-original-tex-contain/505664#505664).) LuaTeX I haven't looked at, but as it's C code instead of WEB (Pascal) code, it will take some effort to compare.

Comment: @ADJenks Overleaf.com has largely solved the problems I mentioned before. Latex really needed for some company to find a way to monetize it and improve quality of life for people. Overleaf guys did just that.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Thanks! It's good to know, even if it took some time to find an answer ;)

Answer (score 56):

The short answer is 'No' as LaTeX is the incumbent and quite good at its job. It's also free, so there is relatively little commercial incentive to attempt to replace it. In fact, TeX is sufficiently good at technical publishing that the commercial market for technical publishing tools is rather squeezed between TeX at the 'geek' end and word at the 'great unwashed' end.

The longer answer is 'There are alternatives'. LaTeX and other packages suffer heavily from [leaky abstraction](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html) issues and often require technical intervention to get what you want out of it. This puts you in the business of understanding how it works behind the scenes, which is actually fairly technical. Thus, you can only really use it for non-casual applications if you have access to someone with that level of technical skill. Writing a report or book is fine. Building a single-source technical documentation workflow with LaTeX is quite a different proposition - you will need access to someone with a technical skill base.

**Alternatives to LaTeX**

- Commercial technical publication
  tools. There is really only one
  left standing: [Framemaker](http://tryit.adobe.com/uk/framemaker/?sdid=DTBUI). 
  This is a mature product but
  somewhat stagnant. However, it does
  have an open document and segment
  interchange format called [MIF](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FrameMaker/8.0/mif_reference.pdf),
  a comprehensive API and extensive
  support for structured
  documentation. It's quite widely
  used in aerospace circles (for
  example) where reference documents
  for aircraft run to tens of
  thousands of pages. Additionally,
  there are 
  several also-rans in this space:
  [Ventura Publisher](http://www.corel.com/servlet/Satellite/us/en/Product/1152105061811#tabview=tab0), 
  [Arbortext](http://www.ptc.com/products/arbortext/) (which is based on a
  TeX derived back-end IIRC), and 
  [Interleaf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interleaf), which is now known
  as Quicksilver.
  Adobe [claim](http://www.adobe.com/products/indesign/features/) to be implementing 
  technical publishing functionality in 
  [InDesign](http://www.adobe.com/products/indesign/) but I have not really 
  evaluated its capabilities for this.
- [Lout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lout_%28software%29) A markup language with a
  completely different underlying
  architecture to TeX. I've never
  worked with Lout but I believe that
  it is somewhat easier to work on
  behind the scenes than TeX.
- [Troff/Groff.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groff_%28software%29) Originally designed for technical documentation within AT&T during the 1970s (actually a spinoff of the UNIX R&D work), it's still quite widely used for this today. For quite a long time most if not all O'Reilly books were typeset using it.
- [DocBook](http://www.docbook.org/).  This is an XML tag
  based format for structure
  documentation, and tends to work by
  rendering through foreign engines. 
  I've never used DocBook, so I can't
  really comment on its usage in
  practice.
- [Wordperfect](http://www.corel.com/servlet/Satellite/us/en/Product/1151523326841#tabview=tab4). This is a
  venerable word processing system
  that is considerably better at 
  documentation-in-the-large than MS-Word. 
  Although viewed as something of an
  also-ran it retains several niche
  markets such as law offices and is
  reasonably good (at least significantly
  better than Word) for large, complex
  and heavily cross-referenced documents.
- [Microsoft Word](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word/FX100487981033.aspx). Not
  recommended for serious technical
  publication tasks due to its
  instability on complex documents.
  However, as often as not it is the 
  only choice due to political 
  constraints. Indexing is especially 
  painful.

**EDIT:** See [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371654/application-not-a-markup-language-for-producing-a-user-manual#372017) for a more in-depth rundown on Framemaker and other technical documentation tools. It's an answer to a question about technical documentation tools for someone who specifically didn't want to use a markup language based system.

Comment: WP&Word: not to mention that documents created with both look *ugly*

Comment: Word 2007 with mathtype can create tex format. And take it in, also.

Comment: That doesn't really absolve word from its other sins - Word (in particular) has many flaws that make it somewhat fraught to use for large technical documents.

Comment: Html and CSS can increasingly be used for typesetting purposes. E.g. see [weasyprint](http://weasyprint.org) for an open-source software that renders html+css to pdf.

Comment: QuarkXPress & Adobe InDesign are far superior than TeX/LaTex. Time to move on.

Comment: Typst is a new one: https://typst.app/

Answer (score 21):

Have you had a look at [ConTeXt](http://www.berenddeboer.net/tex/)? It's a set of macros for  TeX that can be used instead of LaTeX.

I haven't used it myself but the syntax in the example documents looks simpler than LaTeX in a number of cases.

Comment: I use it a lot and much prefer it to LaTeX.  Excellent.

Answer (score 14):

I have already published five books typeset in ConTeXt four of which were museum catalogues with high-quality colour illustrations. It is definitely production ready.

Comment: do you have links to the books you wrote using context?

Answer (score 11):

TeX is actually a fairly special purpose typsetting system.  It does what it does well, but there isn't a large enough need for something better.  "When he designed TeX, Donald Knuth did not believe that a single typesetting system would fit everyone's needs" ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX#Use_of_TeX))

Most of the "newer" systems build guis and extend TeX, which I believe is the right approach.

There are very good reasons for the 'issues' you are facing, so if you want to propose that it be done differently please research those reasons first.

Second, you yourself indicate that TeX is great except for a few minor quibbles.  Knuth built it expressly knowing that it wouldn't be suitable for all uses and all people, but he released the source code and built an extension API so that anyone could adapt it for their needs.

You have all the tools you need to make the changes you propose, and it will be far easier to update TeX than to start from scratch, or even adapt any other system.  Truly, nothing comes close to TeX.  That's not to say that it's the best, but merely to drive home the point that it would be a monumental effort to implement all the good things you mention and somehow overcome the bad (although by the time you get to the bad you may better understand why it exists).

Regardless, I hope you pursue this, even as an advocate, and get others interested in it.  It would be great to see take up of TeX in other fields, but that does require modification and update for ease of use and a better support of other technical entities than mathematical equations.

-Adam

Comment: "extension API"? Huh? I didn't see anything about that in my copy of *TeX the program*...

Comment: @NormanRamsey: whatsits aren't quite what I'd call an *API*, though they certainly are handy for passing extension-related information through the engine...

Answer (score 10):

TeX and LaTeX set the bar high; it's hard to imagine something entirely new coming along and replacing them.

I've got a copy of Knuth's *Computer Modern Typefaces* (Book E in the *Computers And Typesetting* series, which I think *is* completed unlike TAOCP).  I don't think many people get to see this book, and - indulge me - it really is worth looking at.  You can see where some of Kunth's time went.  Here's a quote from the preface:

> Another piece of luck came my way in
>   1984, when I learned that the original
>   bronze patterns used to make the molds
>   of Monotype 8A were in San Francisco. 
>   For years I had been working with
>   indirect and imprecise information
>   about the fonts that had stimulated
>   this work.  First I had worked from
>   photographic blowups of letterpress
>   original pages from *The Art of
>   Computer Programming*; then Richard
>   Southall had prepared enlargements
>   from original proofs he had located in
>   England.  At last I found the actual
>   80-year-old patterns that had
>   generated the metal type.  The present
>   owner of these patters, Mr. Othmar
>   Peters, kindly consented to let me
>   borrow them while I was preparing the
>   final draft of Computer Modern, and I
>   learned much by measuring them with
>   calipers.

You just don't get that kind of attention to detail in many places, and that's why TeX endures.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot retain "it has many extensions to reach different goals" with something new. By definition something new that is not TeX/LaTeX will start with no extension.

Having been a core contributor to the [GNU TeXmacs](http://texmacs.org/) project, which aims to be something like "TeX except for the 21st century", I think have some good insight on the succession of LaTeX.

I am not aware of anything on the horizon that is any likely of dethroning LaTeX. The people of influence in the mathematical community are just too used to using LaTeX to seriously consider the effort required to learn any tool that could be equally flexible.

Maybe in 20 years, when all the folks that got their PhD when LaTeX was cool are retired will something else replace it. Hopefully, it will be something like TeXmacs, but without the unnecessary complexity.

Comment: "Maybe in 20 years" will only happen if the students of tomorrow have a tool that's better than tex now.  If we wait until 20 years to start on the successor, they will all be using tex and it'll be another 20 years.

Comment: Right. There is a chiken and egg problem.

Comment: I'm 34, wrote my PhD thesis using LaTeX, and everyday when I have to use word I'm really happy that I could use LaTeX for my thesis...

Comment: Hey, "people of influence" are actually way more democratically minded and wouldn't mind if you write in some other good math typesetting system... if only there was one :^)

Comment: Some aspects of LaTeX the language (especially the math notation) will likely be around for the forseable future. But the documents won't be typset by LaTeX anymore but by systems like ConTeXt or XML based formatters (which will probably use programs like LuaTeX).

Comment: There is "some other good math typesetting system". It's called TeXmacs.

Answer (score 9):

You have [LuaTeX](http://www.luatex.org).

Quote: "LuaTeX is an extended version of pdfTeX using Lua as an embedded scripting language. The LuaTeX projects main objective is to provide an open and configurable variant of TeX while at the same time offering downward compatibility."

Lua is very easy and fast, so hopefully LuaTeX will not be as hard anymore... hopefully :)

Comment: There seem to be some changes in perspective in the LaTeX world: XeTeX for font rendering and utf8, ConTeXt with more homogenous language constructs. If LuaTeX merges all that and is more hackable, there should be a bright future for a better LaTeX!

Comment: @Piotr: But ConTeXt is *not* LaTeX and does not aim to *be* LaTeX. I think you meant to say "in the TeX world".

Answer (score 9):

org-mode, an Emacs extension, is able to generate LaTeX and PDF files. org-mode syntax is similar to Markdown. It's just **readable**. There are only several LaTeX code lines inside the 20KB document. org-mode resolves three problems you mentioned - you get all the awesome features from LaTeX and get rid of its ugly syntax.

Answer (score 7):

You might also be interested in [XeTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XeTeX), which is a modern version of LaTeX in that it supports Unicode and many fonts. You can use it to directly input Japanese, Arabic etc. in one document. (This doesn't address the disadvantages that you gave, but it's still relevant to the discussion about LaTeX' shortcomings and alternative systems! )

Comment: I thought XeTeX was just yet another patch for TeX (like pdfTeX, eTeX, etc. but more intrusive), which can be used *with* LaTeX...

Comment: new to tex/latex (although i did first dabbled with it in the 1990s) here; boy is this an idiosyncratic system. feels ancient. right now i am trying to use it for typesetting a chinese / japanese / korean /english multilingual book, and if you are into 'unicode' (i.e. anything beyond US-ASCII), my present opinion is that XeTeX (XeLaTeX) is the best choice. that said, it is still painful. but hey i can use true type in 2013 like so: `\usepackage{fontspec} \usepackage{xeCJK} \newCJKfontfamily\hiraganaFont[Path=/home/flow/own/resources/fonts/]{KozGoPro-Heavy.otf}` (no trailing slash -> boom)

Answer (score 7):

[www.patoline.org](http://www.patoline.org) is a great alternative to TeX/LaTeX systems. It has already been packaged for Arch Linux, NixOS, and can be compiled from source on many Unix-like systems.

Comment: Did the Arch package get removed? I can't find any package with a name that includes "patoline" in the official repos or the AUR :/

Comment: Yes, it was removed for some reason. As Patoline is still under development I'm not going to put it back there. The current best way of installing Patoline is explained on GitHub (https://github.com/patoline/patoline).

Answer (score 6):

TeX is not a general purpose typesetting system: its core proficiency is in typesetting long texts with lots of math. In that it doesn't have any competition, I can imagine several reasons:

- Donald Knuth was smart. He did amazing job with, for example, spacing in formulas.
- Math notation changes across periods of time like centuries. There's a limited set of features that is necessary and thus no market for new typesetting systems.
- Network effects. The only purpose of paper is to be read. Most papers advance on some others' research and are using their notation. With TeX you're sure you get the same fonts and the same spacing, and you have a technical ability to copy complex formulas from their papers.
- In TeX it's trivial to define new macro, it's usually easy to say what a simple macros does from its definition and there many standard macro libraries. Any GUI-based system would likely make this process much less transparent.

While the drawbacks you quoted are real, it's much easier to look around for a decent editor/GUI shell built on top of TeX, of which are many, than to typeset in a different language. If you're into math, and want your articles to be preserved for decades, that is. For the general purpose typesetting, again, the programs you mentioned could well be a better choice.

Comment: “While the drawbacks you quoted are real, it's much easier to look around for a decent editor/GUI shell built on top of TeX”: or use TeX as the final rendering stage and edit the content an other way, like semantic markup (ex. MathML, DITA, and so on).

Comment: Hmm, let's say 'compared to WYSIWYG typesetting systems'.

Answer (score 6):

**THE DREAM TOOL IS NOT TEX**

TEX is not great to work with. Tex is probably (I am not an expert in printing matters) good to provide a layer decoupling document from printing niceties and complexities.

*The conceptual line is this :*
A mathematician is not a secretary, his main concern is **WHAT** he wants to show, not **HOW** to show it. 
So one more layer of abstraction is needed above that of Latex.

*General goal* :
Hence there is a need (a dream) for a tool that allows to be much closer to what we can do by hand and of course faster than by hand (in fact I once saw a written answer scanned in .pdf catching red-handed one of the main author of Latex in not using it!).

*Dream Tool specifications* : (rough one to get the idea)
 S1. About an hour of initial time in the learning curve.
 S2. Allow to write a document quickly (by simple analogy) even when tired.
 S3. Cut and paste of seen formula available.
 S4. To correct a document faster than by hand (2 minutes instead of 5 by hand).

*Today best tools abilities*  :
 S1. About the same.
 S2. Impossible while thinking about something else.
 S3. Cut and paste of formula description (implementation).
 S4. It take 20 minutes instead of 5 by hand (everything is specific you have to decipher back and forth).

Another example of sluggishness : Ask someone who wrote a latex document with 10 diagrams in category theory to draw all the squared ones in a slanted way, certainly not a quick job.

Comment: Some mathematicians are really picky about their notation, and high-level-only tools are unable to provide what they want. (Also, WYSIWYG has all that hidden state, which can be painful.) Not to say that TeX is the best possible thing ever, or anything, or even that it's all that great, but I'm not sure how your paradigm is supposed to actually be better...

Comment: This post is not an answer to the question but I agree with it!

Comment: Elsewhere on this page hsk81 mentions NoTex, which abstracts (La)TeX further using reStructuredText as basic markup language, and some pattern matching (macro?) language so you can write your LaTeX markup elsewhere and just put your pattern in your text. My major problem with TeX is that I need to put words in my sentences to make it do something I don't in particular want to be reminded about when reading and writing the text.

Answer (score 6):

After all this time, nobody told something very important.

LaTeX texts are written in a text file, it can be used for **Literate programming**, an style proposed by Don Knuth to write very well documented programs. The idea is to explain how the program was developed in a way similar to math text. Pieces of code are presented like the formulas, in mathematical texts. 
This is a great idea, after some time you can read how the program was conceived and you can modify the parts explaining why the decision was taken in the same way.

Other advantage is that **you can generate LaTeX code as an output of your programs**, in this way you can publish your results beautifully typeset, or use programs like gnuplot to generate graphs then generate LaTeX code for the graph and insert it in your text, that is great because the resulting file is very light compared to graphs exported to some image format, to include it with `\includegraphics` or worse if you are using some word processor by pasting it.

LaTeX is not really hard to learn, just take your pace, use what you need starting with simple documents. When you advance in your studies you will need to learn new features and packages. If you try to master LaTeX by learning all the packages just to become a LaTeX expert, you are wasting your time, there is a huge amount of packages, but you don't need to learn them all. Try to start with guides like *"the not so short introduction to LaTeX"* lshort.pdf, or *"A Gentle Introduction to TeX"* gentle.pdf. 
If you are tired of typing long macros, learn to write your own for the pieces you use more, the guides have a section about that.

Where to find information, in ctan.org, tug.org, *do not* search in latex.com that domain stands for the rubber material.

There is a TeX/LaTeX Catalog, search it in ctan.org it is very helpful when you need an special feature. You can find it here http://texcatalogue.sarovar.org/index.html, but you can search texcatalogue if this link becomes outdated.

To finish my comment, there is a great advantage that LaTeX and other software do not change of versions frequently, TeX/LaTeX is a very complete system for typesetting, you can add (and share) more features if you need something that does not exist.
**Learning LaTeX is a good time investment, you just need to learn it once, then dedicate to do you work, not to learn the new version.**

P.S. 
I forgot to say that it is possible to write programs to translate LaTeX to other markup languages, (and word processors formats if documented) and *vice versa*. In deed there are several that give acceptable results, although as far as I know there is not yet a program that translates any LaTeX code, but for the more common texts you can find several programs to translate them to HTML, LibreOffice can export a word processor document to LaTeX, although it is not very useful because few word processor users use the tags to mark paragraphs as headers, quotations, etc. the vast majority mark the text to change the font, size, alignment, etc. and this is translated into LaTeX. 
But you may need to do this when collaborating with people that use word or LibreOffice, and you have to integrate it with you LaTeX text, just ask them to use the right markings or export it as text and insert the needed macros manually, after all you have to review the whole text of your collaborator.

Once there was need to translate it to HTML to publish on the net or make portable presentations, but now the bandwidth allows to transmit PDF files fast, and packages like beamer allows one to write very nice presentations.

The advantages of TeX/LaTeX are of the size of the packages that can be written on it an the will to share them.  Thanks  to Knuth for his great ideas, we are still waiting the full set of his Art of Computing Programming.

Comment: “To finish my comment, there is a great advantage that LaTeX and other software do not change of versions frequently”: yes, except it unfortunately is not Unicode aware, which is a big issue in the real world. Basically, that's biggest grief I have with it.

Comment: “Thanks to Knuth for his great ideas, we are still waiting the full set of his Art of Computing Programming”: it is not finished? What's missing?

Comment: @Hibou57 Just for information, both XeTeX and (I think) LuaTeX expect Unicode input. The latter is replacing pdfTeX.

Answer (score 5):

I think [docbook](http://www.docbook.org) is supposed to be an open xml based replacement for LateX.

"DocBook provides a system for writing structured documents using SGML or XML. It is particularly well-suited to books and papers about computer hardware and software, though it is by no means limited to them.

"In short, DocBook is an easy-to-understand and widely used DTD. Dozens of organizations use DocBook for millions of pages of documentation, in various print and online formats, worldwide."

-- From the [doc book faq](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/docbook/)

Comment: I say that one downside of LaTeX is too much typing and you present me a XML-based language as alternative? Docbook has it's advantages, but I prefer to generate docbook-sources from something else.

Comment: For trying to write a book or documentation, you can't beat docbook.  It's a different field than TeX, which is for typesetting and TeX is wonderful for math writing, but for prose this xml based format is better.

Comment: Shmeh, 'twas just an offer.  Scorn it if you will.

Comment: It really shouldn't be a big jump from those used to writing in LateX to DocBook. Disagree that DocBook should be generated from something else; what else is there that has the same degree of semantic expressiveness as DocBook? (besides LateX obviously :)

Comment: DocBook is for structuring documents, not typesetting them. In fact it probably uses TeX to generate documents for print.

Comment: When DocBook does not provides the required markup, there is DITA, which is extensible by mean of type derivation from a core set of elements. It's independent from any rendering technology, so could use TeX or LaTeX for rendering to PDF or DVI. The reference implementation, DITA‑OT, is already PDF aware, except it do so via XSL‑FO, not TeX. I guess the same could be achieved using TeX instead of XSL‑FO (which are similar in many ways).

Answer (score 5):

That doesn't really cut into the main disadvantages of LaTeX, but no matter :) Regarding your point

- "sometimes you have to type too much (begin{itemize} ... \end{itemize})"

this is entirely by design. There is a tradeoff between terse (and easier to type) and understandable (and longer to type). Longer names also have fewer collisions, since TeX and LaTeX don't support namespaces (unfortunately).

Anyway, a good editor will obviate the complaint above. Set up key-bindings or tab-completions or whatever else takes your fancy and you never have to write

```
\begin{whatever}...\end{whatever}
```

ever again.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the issue of graphics being hard to position, your other criticisms of LaTeX are more to do with its UI or lack thereof.

If you want to use LaTeX to produce your documents but want an easier way to use it then you should really check out LyX. It's a GUI front-end to LaTeX and address several of your issues: it makes LaTeX easier to learn (in fact, you don't have to even know LaTeX to create a simple, mathless document), it's more intuitive, and it saves you typing. It also adds spell-checking, better graphics handling, navigation, and more.

Because LyX is merely a front-end to LaTeX you still get beautifully presented documents. LyX documents are also plain text so version control works well. In fact, LyX has support for subversion built-in.

If you haven't already guessed, I heartily recommend LyX. I wrote my entire [PhD thesis](http://threewordslong.com/blog/entry/56/The_Reviews_Are_In) using it and found it very worthwhile.

Comment: I really have no problem using a good text-editor. One of the advantages I mentioned is the text-based format for teX-documents. I don't need an UI, but I wish sometimes a clearer, simpler syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Your four disadvantages can be summarized as "It's too hard", "It's too hard", "It's too hard" and finally, "It's too hard".  I think the solution then is to learn how to use the system properly.

Any system that is designed for a novice will show deficiencies in other ways, loss of control or loss of flexibility.  Try MS Word if you want it to be easier to place images.  There's no way around simplicity without effort of learning the program.  TeX supports definition macros, so you can change that \begin{itemize} tag into something more palatable like \bi if you so choose. Once you have sufficiently learned your nook of the LaTex world, it's just as fast as regular typing.

I used to practice taking notes in a math class by writing in TeX, because it was faster to write in \sum_{n=1}^i than trying to find the symbols in MS Word.

Comment: Placing images is a somewhat unfortunate choice of example for MS-word ;-}

Comment: I'm not sure it's that hard. But there is just too many existing documents and users, too much functionality in LaTeX packages, and the underlying technologies are not that well documented or even standardized (font formats...). The amount of work needed to duplicate that is immense, and there is not enough need nor skilled individuals to undertake it. But I believe LuaTeX is a nice path for evolution.

Comment: ...placing images in MS word/openoffice is just as bad as latex in my opinion... I was trying to put a bunch of graphics in an already written document in word and openoffice... god, what a waste of time. At least i know what latex is capable of and can work around it. i guess i just don't know word/oo that well.

Comment: Placing images is exactly one of the things LaTeX does *better* than MS Word, for those of us who just want the images to be *around here somewhere*. Every single time I use MS Word for a technical document, I wonder how the heck MS hasn't gotten around to adding support for floats like LaTeX has!

Comment: It's not too hard. LaTeX is just a PITA compared to human readable syntax like Markdown.

Answer (score 3):

Not really a successor, but you may want to look at *roff (groff, troff, nroff).  I don't know much about it but I remember its format being terse.  It is the tool used for man pages.  Since I have only ever heard of it in passing, I can't give you any more help with it.

For example:

```
        .pl 10.0i
        .po 0
        .ll 7.2i
        .lt 7.2i
        .nr LL 7.2i
        .nr LT 7.2i
        .ds RF FORMFEED[Page %]
        .ds LH Internet Draft
        .\"   --> Header/footers: Set short title, author(s), and dates:
        .ds CH 2-nroff.template                  \" <Short title>
        .ds LF Postel, Braden                    \" <Authors>
        .ds RH October 25, 2006                  \" <Submission date>
        .ds CF Expires April 2007                \" <Expiration date>
        .hy 0
        .ad l
        .nf
        .\" 5678901234567 check 72 column width 12345678901234567890123456789012
        Internet Draft                                                 J. Postel
        <draft-rfc-editor-nroff-template-00.txt>                      RFC Editor
        Category: Informational                                          USC ISI
        Expires April 2007                                      October 25, 2006

        .ce
        Nroff Template for Internet Drafts and RFCs
        .ce
        <draft-rfc-editor-nroff.template-00.txt>

        .in 3              \"  Basic indent for text is 3 spaces
        .ti 0              \"  "Temporary indent" for next line: 0 spaces
        Status of this Memo

        Distribution of this memo is unlimited.

        By submitting this Internet-Draft, each author represents that any
        applicable patent or other IPR claims of which he or she is aware
        have been or will be disclosed, and any of which he or she becomes
        aware will be disclosed, in accordance with Section 6 of BCP 79.

        Internet-Drafts are working documents of the Internet Engineering Task
        Force (IETF), its areas, and its working groups. Note that other groups
        may also distribute working documents as Internet-Drafts.

        Internet-Drafts are draft documents valid for a maximum of six months
        and may be updated, replaced, or obsoleted by other documents at any
```

Comment: He asked for successor, not predecessor ;-)
[Whatever "market" the *roffs had -- beyond manpages -- now entirely belong to the TeXs.]

Comment: Couldn't agree more, LaTex and DocBook are the weapons of choice, but it is terse you gotta give it that. And s/he did want to type less.

Comment: Much as I like troff, I don't think it is a successor to TeX/LaTeX.

Answer (score 3):

XSL-FO might suit your needs. While it's not nearly as powerful as TeX, it does play well with XML formats like DocBook. A popular open source implementation is Apache FOP: http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/.

If you need very fine control over typography, you're better off with TeX or a proprietary tool like FrameMaker or InDesign*.

*beware: InDesign currently has weak XML support IMO

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard anyone suggest that it might actually be useful to write XSL-FO before!

Comment: yikes! take it away!!

Comment: XSL-FO holds great promise. Today, with an up to date build of pandoc and fop you can transform from ReST (or Markdown, or whatever) to Docbook to XSL-FO to PDF without having to wrestle with cranky TeX macros in the process. This doesn't require writing any content in XML.

Answer (score 3):

I just stumbled upon  [AsciiDoc](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc) which looks like a simple text markup language (á la markdown, textile), but it's a lot more powerful.  It's roughly equivalent with DocBook, so it can emit html, pdf, or even docbook xml for further processing.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out Wikipedia's categories [Typesetting programming languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Typesetting_programming_languages) and [Free typesetting software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Free_typesetting_software). [Lout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lout) in particular sounds nice.

Answer (score 2):

I have only skimmed through it, but Emacs Muse http://mwolson.org/projects/EmacsMuse.html might be interesting (I'm interested if any one has more experienced with it. I like the idea of generating to several backends, latex, texinfo or stuff.)

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) is not a replacement of LaTex but something that will make your life easier and that (if desired) generates PDF (via LaTex), HTML or plain text output for you.

It's mostly geared towards code documentation but due to it using [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html), people have found it easier to work with for [other purposes](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/examples.html#homepages-and-other-non-documentation-sites), including [writing books](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/examples.html#books-produced-using-sphinx).

Comment: With [rinohtype](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype), Sphinx can produce PDF output without the need for a LaTeX installation.

Answer (score 1):

Tools for particular jobs:

The strength of Latex2e is that it is a standard document preparation & representation language that is good for the representation of articles and books.  It is, however, not really great for typesetting.  This is not a bad thing: premature formatting is the root of all typesetting evil: most publishers simply throw away author formatting at the beginning of the copy-editing process.

Context is super for typesetting; they cannot compete with Latex as a document representation language, because it does not really solve any problems that should be solved at the document preparation/editing stage, so there is no reason for anyone to change from the well-established latex.

Rather than fix the unimportant-to-publishing flaws of Latex2e through the Latex3 effort, I would rather see effort put into developing the following workflow:

1. Document preparation: Latex2e
2. Copy-editing: Latex2e
3. Conversion: apply tool to take Latex2e -> Context
4. Typesetting: Context
5. Proofreading: make use of tool to check Latex2e content against Context content

---

Postscripts

1. The above workflow pretty much matches the usual workflow, where authoring/editing is done in Word, and typesetting is done using Indesign or Quark Xpress.

Comment: err... why can't we just teach authors (and learn ourselves) to use ConTeXt directly? I'm not seeing how a conversion step of that kind would be at all fun or helpful...

Comment: @SamB: Who is going to do the teaching?  There are tens of thousands of scientific authors who submit papers in Latex.  How are authors  going to react if a publisher tells them to use a completely different markup language for their submissions?  I do not think that Latex is in any danger of being displaced by Context as the lingua franca of scientific publishing.  Word is a much bigger threat.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have noticed the weird version numbers of TeX. When TeX reached version 3 Knuth didn't want TeX to evolve further into new versions like most software does. Instead he wanted it to converge to a final and bug-free TeX. Hence the version number now converges towards the mathematical number pi. After version 3 followed version 3.1, then 3.14 and the current version is 3.1415926.

In a similar fashion Metafont has a version that converges towards the mathematical number e (currently 2.718281).

Based on this, the answer to your question is that Knuth doesn't want TeX to evolve into TeX version 4.

Comment: You know, it just seems weird that the author of *The Art of Computer Programming* does version numbers in what is, in effect, unary notation.

Comment: @DavidThornley: It's not quite so strange if you consider the intended maintenance schedule, as found on [http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html)...